# Couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I am trying to install the newest version of the windows 10 Insider Preview but it comes up with the error that is in the title and I have tried most of the things I've seen on the internet and none of it has worked so can I please have some help

Things I have tried

- DISKPART commands
- Formatting the HDD
- Adding another partition

Many thanks,

Alex Meads

Comment: Have you searched on this site? There are A LOT of this type of question sitting that have been answered.
Also... What other hardware are you rocking. Multiple HDDs/SSDs?

Comment: I am using a Verbatim USB and this is what has the installation media on and a mouse and yes I have looked on this website

Comment: Given that Verbatim have 318 separate USB drives, simply saying Verbatim USB doesn't help. Is it a USB 2.0 or 3.0? Are you trying to install it to an SSD/HDD/Hybrid. Giving vague replies to questions that I ask will provoke vague answers chief. I only want to help. You might want to update your question with more information like what your build is, and an example of what you've tried... Not just "I've tried everything" because there is NO WAY you're the only one with this particular instance of this problem.

Comment: I am trying to install to a HDD and I will update it now

Comment: Maybe try a different USB stick if you have one laying around?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had this problem a couple of months ago. A couple of things to check would be that:

- Your bios allows USB installation
- IF it's a usb 3.0 stick, some PC's don't get USB 3.0 support from the bios, meaning you'll have to get drivers.

You may need to get a linux drive scanner and scan the HDD for any fragments or tiny partitions that are causing it to throw this in your face. [GParted is a good tool and its free.](http://gparted.org/) but it is VERY dangerous. If you only use it to see what partitions are there, then you should be fine. IF there are any ghost partitions, you can use that to clear the space for the new OS.

Beyond that, I don't know. But if I think of something then I'll update this.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this as I am only 14